# C-Passing an 3d array,allocation and population

Tags: c, arrays

let's say I have a functions below.

```
void function createBands(boolean option) {
  int i, j;
  int ***bands = (int ***)malloc((SIZE + 1) * sizeof(int **));
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    bands[i] = (int **)malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int *));
    for (j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
      bands[i][j] = (int *)malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
  }
  iterator *it =
      createIterator(params); // do not be confused it is a structure with
                              // methods andaeribute just like Iterator class in
                              // java . Methods are poniters to functions.
  repare_array(bands[Size], it);
}
void prepare_array(int **band, iterator *it) { read_array(band, it); }

read_array(int **band, iterator *it) {
  for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    band[i] = (int *)it->next();
}

// Now in Iterator.c  I have the iterator structure with the methods etc I will
// write just some line form iterator.

void *next() {
  byte *b =
      a function that reads bytes form a file and returns byte * CORECTLY !!!;
  return b == NULL ? NULL : bytetoT(b);
  // this function make void form byte conversion but it doesnt work so I make
  // only a cast in read_aray as you see. SUppose just return b wich is byte(i
  // know in C isn't any byte but I redeclared all the types to be JAVA.)
}
```

the questions is where I should allocate the bands because in this situation the 1D vector return by function is ok because I see the values in the function scope. But when it is return to array[i] I got a unallocated 3dVector.
I need to recieve bands[size][i][j] with the data form b. In b the data is good then I ve gote bands null.
What I have do so far I make another allocation in prepare aray before the call to read_array where I allocate **band  and then I have some results but I am not confident.
Sorry for the confusion! And every comment is good for me. Maybe what I have do is ok I do not know!.
I am not new to C I just do not work with pointers for a long time.

Comment: Wrong on many levels... You don't have a 3D array, you have a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer. Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't cast the return of `malloc()`. What is `sizeofint` ?

Comment: I have a 3d image that I want to compress. I have a function that reads 1D array form the image(bytes) then I convert the bytes in int and I am trying to feel an array that represend the image.

Comment: I have a function that uses to allocate malloc with void and then I make the cast. here I wrote the malloc function for better understanding. The problem is that the 3dArray is unallocated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 2D pointer(**) you have to assign it with the address of 2D array and if it is 1D array you have to assign it with the address of 1D array.

For your read_array function

```
             read_array(int**array...)
              {
               for(i=0;i<HEIGHT(the same as in allocation);i++)
                  `enter code here`array[i] = function();//function return an 1D array 
              }
```

Make sure that function() returns the address of the 1D array.

Comment: The function() has de signature: void* function(). and I have array[i]=(int *)function(); I do not solve yet the problem. What I did I reallocated array inside the read_array  but I do not know if this is ok because I have allocated the array once in the first function and then again in the second one.